# kEasyLeaderBoard can write

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

[image]

//Leaderboard Category IDs

## define kEasyLeaderboardID @"net.joviant.Ballonster.easy"//@"com.appledts.EasyTapList"

## define kHardLeaderboardID @"com.appledts.HardTapList"

## define kAwesomeLeaderboardID @"com.appledts.AwesomeTapList"

//Achievement IDs

## define kAchievementGotOneTap @"123"//@"com.appletest.one_tap"

## define kAchievementHidden20Taps @"net.joviant.Ballonster.2ndachievement"//@"com.appledts.twenty_taps"

## define kAchievementBigOneHundred @"net.joviant.Ballonster.3rdachievement" //@"com.appledts.one_hundred_taps"

How can I write kEasyLeaderBoardID ???

Answer (score 0):

You mean write during runtime? You cant rewrite a #define at runtime.. Just pass another string in..

Comment: no no no, my brother I want to use that thing for my this game

Comment: then what you mean by how you write keasyleaderboardID?? Juz change the defined values??

Comment: lol.. juz email me at junxron@gmail.com will do.. haha.. i dun understand wad u trying to ask..